# correct position for c# methods outside from cshtml MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, view

I have in my view ....cshtml in the top a loader e.g. for SVGs

```
@functions {
  public string GetSVG(string path)
  {
    return File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(path));
  }
}
```

But exactly this function I need in "a few views"... Where can I place this method?

HomeController.cs? <- its not the "perfect" solution because in my SecondController.cs I also need this method.

Comment: have you tried making a helper class and then declare that function as static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your implementation is different from each controller then you can have an abstract class as follows.

```
public abstract class SVG
{
    public abstract string GetSVG(string path);
}


public class MyController : SVG
{
    public override string GetSVG(string path)
    {
         // your implementation
    }
}
```

Otherwise, have a static class and invoke the **GetSVG** method from any controller.

Answer (score 0):

Normally @functions are used when the functionality is closed to a particular view. 
If it is a shared function then a static function in any class would do better or a html helper.